# ¿Cómo usar un rango de fechas con Datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

He estado viendo varias páginas respecto a este tema y encontré una que explica de manera sencilla el uso de rangos solo que lo usan con edad ([range filtering](https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html)).
Luego encontré esta ([range dates](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/filtering/row-based/range_dates)) para usarlo con fechas, pero no me arroja la búsqueda ni siquiera la hace. ¿que estoy haciendo mal? o se necesita más configuraciones, ¿se supone que solo deberíamos cambiar los id de los input, no?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puse mi librería que indica ahí en la página:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/range_dates.js"></script>
```

Luego mi código que indica ahí en la página también:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      var table = $('#exportar').DataTable();

      // Add event listeners to the two range filtering inputs
      $('#min').keyup( function() { table.draw(); } );
      $('#max').keyup( function() { table.draw(); } );
  } );
```

Mis inputs con sus id:

```
 fecha inicio: <input id="min" name="min" type="text" placeholder="Search by Date" />
 fecha final: <input id="max" name="max" type="text" placeholder="Search by Date" />
```

Y por último este cogido es el que viene en la librería **`range_dates.js`** que puse, pero a lo que leí también se configuraba cambiando los id:

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
    function( oSettings, aData, iDataIndex ) {
        var iFini = document.getElementById('#min').value;
        var iFfin = document.getElementById('#max').value;
        var iStartDateCol = 6;
        var iEndDateCol = 7;

        iFini=iFini.substring(6,10) + iFini.substring(3,5)+ iFini.substring(0,2);
        iFfin=iFfin.substring(6,10) + iFfin.substring(3,5)+ iFfin.substring(0,2);

        var datofini=aData[iStartDateCol].substring(6,10) + aData[iStartDateCol].substring(3,5)+ aData[iStartDateCol].substring(0,2);
        var datoffin=aData[iEndDateCol].substring(6,10) + aData[iEndDateCol].substring(3,5)+ aData[iEndDateCol].substring(0,2);

        if ( iFini === "" && iFfin === "" )
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if ( iFini <= datofini && iFfin === "")
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if ( iFfin >= datoffin && iFini === "")
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (iFini <= datofini && iFfin >= datoffin)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
);
```

Comment: ya verificaste que los `substring` que se hacen concuerdan con el formato de fecha que estas ingresando y el que estas mostrando en la tabla?.

Comment: el formato de fecha que ingreso y muestro es asi: Y/m/d y no e revisado el substring para que se utiliza?

Comment: adicional las variables `iStartDateCol y iEndDateCol` estan apuntando a las columnas de tu tabla, esos son los indices?. El ejemplo que dejas filtra un rango de fechas para dos columnas. En tu caso tbn vas a utilizar dos columnas?

Comment: En el ejemplo si ingresas: `30/01/2019` al aplicarle los substring devolvera: `20190130`

Comment: el ejemplo que puse es el que esta en la pagina oficial de datatable lo quería utilizar para mi proyecto lo único que cambie fueron los id, pensado que funcionaria como el plugin datatable que por defualt lanza el search , paginado etc

Comment: En que formato muestras las fechas en tu tabla? favor deja un ejemplo y tambien el indice de la columna donde esta la fecha.

Comment: el formato esta Y/m/d  año-mes-día se almacena en un campo de tipo date y lo muestro 2019-06-12  puse imagenes de la tabla y la base de datos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te dejo el siguiente ejemplo para que pruebes y lo adaptes a tu tabla.

- En el mismo veras que utilizo `replace` para reemplazar los guiones.
- El `indexCol` deberás colocar el índice de la columna. (basado en la imagen que dejas se aprecia que es el índice 1).

El evento keyup:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    var table = $('#exportar').DataTable();

    $('#min,#max').keyup( function() {
        table.draw();
    });
});
```

Búsqueda de rango de fechas:

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function(oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {

        var dateIni = $('#min').val();
        var dateFin = $('#max').val();

        var indexCol = 1;

        dateIni = dateIni.replace(/-/g, "");
        dateFin= dateFin.replace(/-/g, "");

        var dateCol = aData[indexCol].replace(/-/g, "");

        if (dateIni === "" && dateFin === "")
        {
            return true;
        }

        if(dateIni === "")
        {
            return dateCol <= dateFin;
        }

        if(dateFin === "")
        {
            return dateCol >= dateIni;
        }

        return dateCol >= dateIni && dateCol <= dateFin;
    }
);
```

> Recuerda que cualquier cambio de formato de la fechas deberás modificar el `search.push`.
>   Si necesitas comparar solo al ingresar una fecha completa, entonces deberás validar el length (de `dateIni y dateFin`) después del replace que sea igual a 8.

Comment: perfecto ya hace la búsqueda ya toma valores pero hay un detalle por ejemplo si yo puse fecha inicial: 2019-05-14 y fecha final 2019-06-12 me muestra la fecha del 2019-05-13 2019-05-12 esas están fuera del rango seleccionado

Comment: también si pongo un rango de un día de diferencia no me arroja todos los registros que hay solo algunos por ejemplo del 2019-06-11 al 2019-06-12

Comment: a lo mejor es por que en mi tabla tengo mas campos con fechas y toma el valor de los otros campos no ?

Comment: No creo que sea eso. por que la variable `indexCol` indica la columna. al menos que el valor de 1 este apuntando a otra columna. Es muy importante que coloques el indice correcto a `indexCol`

Comment: Cuantas columnas tiene tu tabla, empieza a contar desde cero hasta la columna de la fecha que quieres hacer la busqueda y ese sera el indice.

Comment: perfecto si si era eso de las columnas coloque mal el numero muchas gracias quedo perfecto con tu ejemplo era justo lo que necesitaba

Answer (score 1):

esto utilizo yo en mi tabla para hacer un daterangepicker, espero te pueda servir
mi input es:

```
 "Seleccionar entre fechas: <input id='Date_search' type='text' placeholder='Buscar por Fecha' style='width: 200px' /><br><br>";

minDateFilter = "";
maxDateFilter = "";
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
    function(oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
        if (typeof aData._date == 'undefined') {
            aData._date = new Date(aData[2]).getTime();
        }

        if (minDateFilter && !isNaN(minDateFilter)) {
            if (aData._date < minDateFilter) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        if (maxDateFilter && !isNaN(maxDateFilter)) {
            if (aData._date > maxDateFilter) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
);

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Date_search").val("");
    var groupColumn = 0;
    var table = $('#salarios').DataTable({})
)};


    $("#Date_search").daterangepicker({
        "locale": {
            "format": "DD-MM-YYYY",
            "separator": " hasta ",
            "applyLabel": "Buscar",
            "cancelLabel": "Cancelar",
            "fromLabel": "desde",
            "toLabel": "hasta",
            "customRangeLabel": "Custom",
            "weekLabel": "W",
            "daysOfWeek": [
                "Su",
                "Mo",
                "Tu",
                "We",
                "Th",
                "Fr",
                "Sa"
            ],
            "monthNames": [
                "Enero",
                "Febrero",
                "Marzo",
                "Abril",
                "Mayo",
                "Junio",
                "Julio",
                "Agosto",
                "Septiembre",
                "Octubre",
                "Noviembre",
                "Diciembre"
            ],
            "firstDay": 1
        },
        "opens": "center",
    }, function(start, end, label) {
        maxDateFilter = end;
        minDateFilter = start;
        table.draw();
    });
```

Este es el cdn de daterangepicker:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />
```

Comment: para este ejemplo tengo que usar la librería de daterangepicker.min.js ?

Comment: si, tienes que usar esa libreria

Comment: puse las librerías pero no del cdn sino directas en mi proyecto pero no me funciona ni si quiera me genera los calendarios para tomar la fecha

Comment: @jasieltorres pero te da algún error en la consola?